# Proving F(y) to be negative for all real values of y.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the question,

Show that $F(y)= (6+y)(4-y)(y+4)(y-2)-65$ is negative for all real values of $y$.

What I did, I expanded the expression into $-(5y^4 + 4y^3 - 32y^2 - 64y + 289)$. From there I concluded that for any value of y the value of $F(y)$ will be negative.

I think this answer is too vague and possibly wrong.

Comment: The expansion is still not correct. I believe it should be $-y^4 - 4y^3 + 28y^2 + 64y - 257$.

Comment: Your expansion is correct thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, for the sake of symmetry, we can make the substitution $y=x-1$, so that $$f(x)=(x+5)(5-x)(x+3)(x-3)=(25-x^2)(x^2-9)=-225+34x^2-x^4$$

Differentiating, we find stationary points at $x=0$ and at $x^2=17$ with latter corresponding to symmetrical maxima.

We then get $f(\sqrt{17})=64$

So the function is always less than $65$

Instead of using differentiation ,you can complete the square and write $$f(x)=64-(17-x^2)^2$$ and the conclusion is the same

Comment: User tagged this as precalculus. They might not be able to take derivatives in this question :-)

Comment: Thank you however I require an answer not involving calculus

Comment: One could put $x^2=t$ and then you have a quadratic,you can find the maximum of the quadratic with precalculus.

Comment: Please see my edited answer

Comment: This does all equate however may you actually replace y into another term for your own convenience and on what ground? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @user366384 The original expression that you had, ignoring the $-65$ at the end, has roots at $-6, -4, 2, 4$. If you imagine this graphed, then you would see it is symmetric around $x=-1$; so, shifting to the right by $1$ gives a new expression that has roots at $-5, -3, 3, 5$, which makes everything more symmetrical and pleasant.

Comment: Makes sense thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take the part (using the idea of David):

$$(6+y)(4-y)(y+4)(y-2)\stackrel{y=x-1}\rightarrow(x+5)(5-x)(x+3)(x-3)=$$

$$=-(x^2-25)(x^2-9)=-x^4+34x^2-225$$

Putting $\;t:=x^2\;$ we get the quadratic $\;-t^2+34t-22\;$ , a downward parabola whose vertex (maximum point) is

$$\left(-\frac b{2a}\,,\,\,-\frac\Delta{4a}\right)=\left(-\frac{34}{-2}\,,\,\,-\frac{34^2-4\cdot225}{-4}\right)=\left(17\,,\,\,64\right)\implies$$

the maximum value is $\;64\;$ andwe're done.